# jQuery call to Controller not hitting breakpoint

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

In ASP .NET MVC 4 I'm trying to update a list on the page without performing an actual form submission and without a page refresh.

Upon button click, I'd like to call the list data in the method CheckPartNumber however the breakpoint is never hit.  No errors are thrown.  I can hit a debugger; in the JavaScript but no errors are found.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function getParts(searchString) {
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("CheckPartNumber", "PartController")',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    // we set cache: false because GET requests are often cached by browsers
    // IE is particularly aggressive in that respect
    cache: false,
    data: { searchString: searchString },
    success: function (part) {
        $('#PartNumber').val(part.PartNumber);
        //$('#LastName').val(person.LastName);
    }
});
}
</script>
```

### Markup

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input type="text" id="part" />
        <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="getParts('test')"  /> 
    </div>
```

### Controller

```
public class PartController : Controller
{
    private InventurWebEntities db = new InventurWebEntities();

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CheckPartNumber(string searchString)
    {
        var parts = db.Parts.Take(10);
        return Json(parts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are constructing the wrong URL. When using [`Url.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492758(v=vs.118).aspx) you need to drop the `Controller` suffix. So this:

```
@Url.Action("CheckPartNumber", "PartController")
```

Becomes this:

```
@Url.Action("CheckPartNumber", "Part")
```